# How to solve: JupyterLab codefolding column occlude the first column of my code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, code-folding

After I enabled the codeFolding in my JupyterLab:
Settings->Advanced Settings Editor: add(or change):
"codeCellConfig": {
"codeFolding": true
}
the folding functionality is enabled, however the folding column occludes my code, which trubled me
much, like this
[image]

Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

Close the current Notebook (.ipynb file) that is having this problem and open it again in JupyterLab.

You don't have to restart JupyterLab, just close and open the particular notebooks having this problem.

This issue happens right after you change the code folding settings in JupyterLab.

Answer (score -2):

Web page display problem
Restart jupyter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).